# Eclipse not responding to changes in servlet and HTTP 404 Error

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm running into a problem where whenever I Run As my project on a server, it gives me a HTTP Status 404 Error whenever I try to redirect into my jsp page. It states the requested resource is not available despite the servlet file being present. The problem is, the servlet and jsp files a group mate worked on works when I run as a server, it only does not work when I try to redirect into my files. It's also worth mentioning that when my group mate runs as a server on his end, my servlet and jsp files work so I don't think this is a server issue. I've looked around stackoverflow and I've already cleaned my server, changed the server location to use tomcat installation, and I changed the server properties' location to tomcat 7.0.

Also, when I try to make any changes onto my group mates' servlet files, it doesn't do anything even if it shouldn't compile in the first place.

Attached is an image of going through our project, when I click on Questions or Alerts, it works but when I click on Reservations, it gives me an error.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1zA9.png)

How should I go about fixing this?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
[Image of XML, directory of files, and console server info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIifY.png)

EDITEDIT:
[Servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtEdu.png)

Comment: Can you copy the error stack trace from your console ? That might be more informative. And also your folder/file hierarchy.

Comment: And show the part of the `web.xml` file (or annotations) that shows where everything should be available.

Comment: I attached the XML file, project directory, and what ever the console logged when I started the server. It doesn't log anything in console when I enter my page

Comment: So, there is no mapping in the xml, so in the creatReservation servlet you should have the annotation. It might be also helpful if you provide the code of the servlet. Also, the stack trace you provided is when you start the server, there must be information printed in the console after you clicking at the “ Reservations” button

Comment: I provided the servlet code.There's no information printed in the console after I click reservations hence my assumption that maybe this is a eclipse problem? What do you mean no mapping in the xml?

Comment: Your project icon has a red cross. This usually means that it won't build at all. Never ignore project errors like this. See abovelinked duplicate for clues.